# Tensorflow estimators: feature columns size error in 1.5

Tags: python, tensorflow

When attempting to use a canned estimator for testing my dataset, I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "estimator.py", line 61, in <module>
    model.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=20000)
  File "/home/sid/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 314, in train
    loss = self._train_model(input_fn, hooks, saving_listeners)
  File "/home/sid/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 743, in _train_model
    features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN, self.config)
  File "/home/sid/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/estimator.py", line 725, in _call_model_fn
    model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features=features, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sid/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 324, in _model_fn
    config=config)
  File "/home/sid/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/estimator/canned/dnn.py", line 153, in _dnn_model_fn
    'Given type: {}'.format(type(features)))
ValueError: features should be a dictionary of `Tensor`s. Given type: <class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

I found the same error online [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3331) but it seems like it has been resolved in Tensorflow 1.5. However, I am still receiving the same error, and am using tensorflow 1.5 (CUDA 9.0 and newest cuDNN). This indicates that the issue is most likely something concerning the way I created my dataset using the new dataset api.

estimator.py:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from input_pipe import tr_data, val_data

# Parameters
learning_rate = 1e-4
num_epochs = 2000
batch_size = 128
display_step = 100

# We know that the images are 128x128
img_size = 128

# Images are stored in one-dimensional arrays of this length.
img_size_flat = img_size * img_size

# Tuple with height and width of images used to reshape arrays.
img_shape = (img_size, img_size)

# Number of colour channels for the images: 1 channel for gray-scale.
num_channels = 3

# Number of classes, Dogs and Cats
num_classes = 2

# We import our Dataset objects from input_pipe because we need to be
# able to access them from within our input functions
train_dataset = tr_data
val_dataset = val_data

def train_input_fn():
        tr_data = train_dataset.batch(batch_size)
        tr_data = tr_data.repeat(num_epochs)
        # iterator = tr_data.make_one_shot_iterator()
        iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(tr_data.output_types, tr_data.output_shapes)

        features, labels = iterator.get_next()

        return features, labels

def test_input_fn():
        #iterator = val_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
        iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(tr_data.output_types, tr_data.output_shapes)

        features, labels = iterator.get_next()

        return features, labels


feature_x = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('tr_data.train_imgs',img_shape)


num_hidden_units = [512, 256, 128]

model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=[feature_x],
                hidden_units=num_hidden_units,
                activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                n_classes=num_classes,
                model_dir="./checkpoints")

model.train(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=20000)
```

`input_pipe.py` creates a tensorflow dataset for train and val images. I am quite sure my dataset is working correctly, as I was able to initialize an iterator, loop over the entire set, and print out relevant data.

I believe the issue lies with the feature column arg of the canned estimator, but am unsure as to what I could do to fix it. I have also tried returning an `iterator.get_next()` within my `train_input_fn` and `test_input_fn`, but that didn't change the error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, the only examples I have found regarding estimators online are those dealing with already made datasets, such as the tensorflow mnist one, not with a dataset that someone created from scratch (using the dataset api). Thanks!

Comment: I think the complaint is that the `input_fn` should be returning feature_name: feature_value dictionaries (including a "tr_data.train_imgs" key), but instead is returning single a `Tensor`.

Answer (score 2):

[Allen Lavoie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6824418/allen-lavoie) was correct, I changed my train_input_fn function to:

```
def train_input_fn():
    train_dataset = tr_data.batch(batch_size)
    # train_dataset = train_dataset.repeat()
    # train_dataset = train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=batch_size) 

    iterator = train_dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    features, labels = iterator.get_next()
    x = {'image': features}
    y = labels

    return x, y
```

and it worked. I needed to return a dict of images, with the same key value that I used in my feature column instantiation:

```
feature_image = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('image', shape=[16384*3], dtype=tf.float32)
num_hidden_units = [512, 256, 128]
model = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=[feature_image],
                hidden_units=num_hidden_units,
                activation_fn=tf.nn.relu,
                n_classes=num_classes,
                model_dir="./checkpoints")
```

Hope this helped someone!